# Consul ACL Rule specification (HTTP API)

Tags: acl, consul

I'm trying to modify an ACL token I've just created by sending the following JSON via the HTTP API:

```
{
  "ID": "UUID HERE",
  "Name": "loadbalancer",
  "Type": "client",
  "Rules": "service {policy=read}"
}
```

However, this syntax for my Rules is being rejected. I've also tried sending information in JSON format similar to how it's documented in the ACL Internals page:

```
{
  "ID: "UUID HERE",
  "Name": "loadbalancer",
  "Type": "client",
  "Rules": 
  {
    "service":
    {
      "": { "policy": "read" }
    }
  }
}
```

These are all rejected as having incorrect formatting. What's the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
      "ID: "UUID HERE", ==> missing double quote in "ID"
      "Name": "loadbalancer",
      "Type": "client",
      "Rules": 
      {
        "service":
        {
          "": { "policy": "read" }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue